# Force -webkit-tap-highlight-color on a default element

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a nav bar with highlighting elements when clicked on them. It is working, but I am also trying to have the first element selected/highlighted by default.

When one of them is tapped the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` kicks in and controls the color. I want to make it highlight my first element without tapping/clicking on it.

I tried to apply the `.active` class, but the result is not what I'm looking for, because the effect is different. The `.current` class did not change anything.

My style is coming from https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar&stacked=h

```
       <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [class.current]="index == 0"><a href="#">{{tab}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

I know how to do it with js and events, but was trying to avoid it.

Comment: First try to change name of variable index on something else (for example: `let i = index` and then `[class.current]="i === 0"`

Comment: It does not have any problem in applying the `current` class. The class is applied, but there is no change